# Pandas - inconsistent join behaviour for NaN keys depending on Index or Multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have a simple `left` dataframe and I'd like to left join a `right` dataframe to it using their indexes.

`left` dataframe (Multiindex consisting of `key_1` and `key_2`):

| key_1 | key_2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | a |
| NaN | NaN |

`right` dataframe (`key_1` is index, `desired_column` is a column)

| key_1 | desired_column |
| --- | --- |
| a | desired_value_a |
| b | desired_value_b |

Expected output after the left join:

| key_1 | key_2 | desired_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | desired_value_a |
| NaN | NaN | NaN |

However, I get this:

| key_1 | key_2 | desired_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | desired_value_a |
| NaN | NaN | desired_value_a |

I get `desired_value_a` where `key_1 == NaN`, which seems wrong. I found that if the `left` table only uses `key_1` as its index instead of using `key_1` and `key_2` then I get the correct, expected output instead.

Code to reproduce what I see, where the only difference between the code blocks is the index I set for `left`:

```
# THIS RETURNS MATCHES FOR NAN KEYS, WEIRDLY
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

left = pd.DataFrame({
    'key_1': ['a', np.nan],
    'key_2': ['a', np.nan],
}).set_index(keys=['key_1', 'key_2'])

right = pd.DataFrame({
    'key_1': ['a', 'b'],
    'desired_column': ['desired_value_a', 'desired_value_b'],
}).set_index(keys=['key_1'])

pd.merge(
    left=left,
    right=right,
    how='left',
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
    indicator=True
)
```

```
# THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

left = pd.DataFrame({
    'key_1': ['a', np.nan],
    'key_2': ['a', np.nan],
}).set_index(keys=['key_1'])

right = pd.DataFrame({
    'key_1': ['a', 'b'],
    'desired_column': ['desired_value_a', 'desired_value_b'],
}).set_index(keys=['key_1'])

pd.merge(
    left=left,
    right=right,
    how='left',
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
    indicator=True
)
```

Does anyone know what causes this behaviour and if it's intentional/by design or if it's possibly a bug? Any recommendations on how to make sure I get the expected behaviour (ie join returnin NaN for when the keys are NaN)? Again I could just use single index in THIS scenario, but what to do when I indeed need Multiindex?

I am using Pandas version 1.4.3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess (this is just an hypothesis), as you use `left/right_index=True` for both, a `reindexing` occurs to have the same levels for both DataFrames, which leads to a null level of key_2 for `right`.

Indeed, setting a dummy level for key_2 does not lead to the same issue:

```
right = pd.DataFrame({
    'key_1': ['a', 'b'],
    'key_2': ['a', np.nan],
    'desired_column': ['desired_value_a', 'desired_value_b'],
}).set_index(keys=['key_1', 'key_2'])

pd.merge(
    left=left,
    right=right,
    how='left',
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
    indicator=True
)
```

output:

```
              desired_column     _merge
key_1 key_2                            
a     a      desired_value_a       both
NaN   NaN                NaN  left_only
```

A workaround might be to temporarily `reset_index`:

```
pd.merge(
    left=left.reset_index('key_2'),  # set aside here
    right=right,
    how='left',
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
    indicator=True
).set_index('key_2', append=True)    # restore there
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway ! I don't quite follow your hypotheses, could you elaborate? You suggested the reindexing would lead to a null level of key_2 for the right table. But why would this cause the join operation to find a match for the row in the left table where key_1 == NaN?